# C# : DataGridView cell alignment isn't the same for all the rows?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm again asking about C#. I just finished loading my data on a DataGridView but my problem (not a real problem) is that the cell alignement isn't the same for all the rows, what I want is to make the informations loor normal like any DataGridView but That's what I get :

[image]

I tried to edit the alignement proprety like this :

[image]

But still get the same thing..

EDIT : This is the propreties of my datagridview from designer.cs :

```
// 
        // dataGridView1
        // 
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToOrderColumns = true;
        dataGridViewCellStyle1.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.dataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.id,
        this.forage_id,
        this.caisse_id,
        this.unite_cotes,
        this.cote_tete,
        this.cote_pieds,
        this.systemes,
        this.epoque,
        this.formations,
        this.storage,
        this.categorie,
        this.status,
        this.remarques,
        this.nb_caisses});
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 19);
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1120, 349);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
        //
```

Comment: Could you post your DataGridView properties from your Designer.cs file?

Comment: I posted them. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

set Alignment of Every Column programatically:-

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns[column-name].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it changed the alignement of some rows, not all of them.. this is what I got ( I changed the 2nd row)  :http://prntscr.com/49qwe0

Comment: Use it for every column. Just change Column name

Comment: I did, but it changed the 1st,3rd,5th rows .. the 2nd,4th ... still the same.. prntscr.com/49qwe0

Comment: Than also set AlternatingCellStyle property same as above. Place AlternatingCellStyle instead of DefaultCellStyle

Comment: It didn't work @yash, but thanks a lot for ur answers!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are setting the style only for alternating rows, not the `DefaultCellStyle`. Take a look at this code that I wrote to test your problem.

```
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToOrderColumns = true;
    DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
    cellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

    // Replace this
    //dataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle = cellStyle;
    // With this
    dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle = cellStyle;

    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1, "Test", 14, "Long String With Spaces");
    }
```